# run flutter doctor command facing Network resources issue

Tags: windows, flutter-doctor

X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://github.com/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have          [image]malware installed on your computer.

I have attempted all the solutions found on the internet, such as setting the date and time and turning off Windows Defender, but I am still facing the same issue.